# Non blocking command process

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm attempting to run command :

```
! sudo chromium-browser --no-sandbox www.google.com
```

via command line

I've also tried :

```
! sudo chromium-browser --no-sandbox www.google.com
```

and added to sh script file where output is :

```
sudo ./ruunn.sh
 --disable-quic --enable-tcp-fast-open --disable-gpu-compositing --ppapi-flash-path=/usr/lib/chromium-browser/libpepflashplayer.so --ppapi-flash-args=enable_stagevideo_auto=0 --ppapi-flash-version=
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/fonts.conf", line 160: blank doesn't take any effect anymore. please remove it from your fonts.conf
[8232:8232:1210/204151.324275:ERROR:gpu_process_transport_factory.cc(1029)] Lost UI shared context.
[8232:8327:1210/204151.671927:ERROR:bus.cc(394)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
ATTENTION: default value of option force_s3tc_enable overridden by environment.
[8331:8331:1210/204154.008745:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(375)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
```

The browser opens successfully. The issue is the python script is not returning preventing other commands from being executed. Is there a way to execute the command without blocking ? I'm executing these commands in jupyter notebook.

Comment: nohup with shell=True?

Comment: spawn a new thread for the shell job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you trail a bash command with `&` then it becomes non-blocking. There's more detail about that [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86247/what-does-ampersand-mean-at-the-end-of-a-shell-script-line)

> With & the process starts in the background, so you can continue to use the shell and do not have to wait until the script is finished.

So for your case

```
! sudo chromium-browser --no-sandbox www.google.com &
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look on [screen command](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-use-linux-screen/).